# Как лучше кэшировать данные, полученные из интернета?

Tags: java, android

Всем добра , беру json  данные с api, думаю эти данные хранить(кэшировать) в базе Sqlite,правильно ли я задумал,если нет подскажите как реализовать кэширование в приложении?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все зависит от обьема данных. Если их много то я не вижу проблем в использовании SQLite. Если же не так много то можно хранить JSON файл как строку в `SharedPreferences` а потом ее распарсить при получении, [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918328/is-it-ok-to-save-a-json-array-in-sharedpreferences) пример. Но я бы все таки использовал SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

Тут еще вопрос возникает. А на какое время вам эти данные нужны? На время жизни приложения если то можно использовать либо синглетон, либо например у Okhttp есть своя реализация кеша.